# Personal Project Classifying Bank Account Data - NLP Noob

Tags: nlp, multiclass-classification, spacy, huggingface

Background:

I'm looking to get up to speed with some of the newer ML classification techniques and keep my ML python fresh in my spare time/learn some new skills, so as a challenge I'm trying to see if I can beat some of the budgeting apps with their classification (and make the tagging a bit more personal). I use Mint and have easy access to my own banking data so have a good way to benchmark this little project. Data is < 100 characters, unstructured (I'm not going to share my personal data as thats all I have at the moment, but to give an idea of the structure I'm using have a look at your csv bank statement!).

Ideally I'd love to have way to tag a couple of "levels" e.g. Restaurants and Eating Out : Coffee shop with the merchant name e.g. Starbucks cleansed too.

Context:

I work in Python, familiar with Tensorflow (but use more for gradient descent type optimizations in my day to day work). I haven't done any NLP in over 10 years. Back then I used Naive Bayes classifier which took some heavy lift... things have come on A LOT since then.

So few questions:

- What are the current tools people use for this type of exercise. I've read about spaCy, huggingface - are these the main tools used? What are the pros cons to each if so? (without sounding too old... there is so much off the shelf nowadays since I last looked at this space... props to the open source community!!!)
- Any other tools I should be considering?
- Any good articles people have read where people have tried to implement this problem? Any good online resources tackling this?
- Any gotchas I should watch out for?
- Any public large datasets anyone is aware of I could use?
- And also I plan to do this in Python, because that's what I'm familiar with, but if people are tackling this in a different language I'd love to hear which and why (and maybe I'll give it a spin).